# named tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use named tuples as follows:

```
from collections import namedtuple
thermometer = namedtuple('thermometer', 'name, max, min')
mac_dict = {
            "1234" : thermometer("warehouse1", 15, 17),
            "123B" : thermometer("warehouse2", 11, 19),
            "124C" : thermometer("serverroom", 12, 34)
           }

mac_address = "1234"
print mac_dict[mac_address].thermometer.max
```

But this ends with:

```
AttributeError: 'thermometer' object has no attribute 'thermometer'
```

Can I fix it somehow?

Comment: why are you doing `.thermometer`??? If you had a list instead, you wouldn't do `mac_dict[mac_address].list[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says

```
mac_dict[mac_address]
```

**is** the thermometer.

Just address its max with

```
mac_dict[mac_address].max
```